# How can I make a toboggan to study projectile motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, experimental-physics

I'm currently working on an experiment due in a month in which I have to recreate this toboggan :

[image]

I would drop a ball at the top of it on the left and let it slide. I would then study the trajectory of the ball after exiting the toboggan (projectile motion study).

The point of it is to study how the angle and speed of the ball will affect its trajectory.

Using $E_p = E_c$ we would get an initial speed of $v = \sqrt{2gH}$ ; and an angle of $\alpha$.

Therefore we should be able to manipulate and change the height $H$ and the angle $\alpha$. However me and my physics teacher can't sort it out. I thought of using a silicone tube but it would require to be quite large to welcome the ball. Do you guys have any idea?

Also I have a question : will the mass of the ball affect the initial speed? With $v = \sqrt{2gH}$ it seems like it won't but just to be sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can use any material provided that it should give minimal resistance..

And about your second question the initial speed of ball wont be affected but when the ball is in air it will experience drag due to air so heavier ball will experience less drag as compared to a lighter one.

And best of luck for your experiment :)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I think I'm going to order a larger silicon tube (it's quite cheap apparently). Happy to know a lighter ball will be better, I thought it was the opposite. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Hugosh Sorry my bad i just read that heavier ball will be less affected by drag  drag you are correct I'm so sorry  I will edit my answer. Think I got confused

Comment: @Hugosh.  Given two balls of the same size, the heavier ball will experience *less* drag.  You want a heavier ball (like a steel ball).

Comment: @march yup you are right i got confused

Comment: @Shardul hey no worries thanks for the help. Also what diameter do you think I should get the ball? The interior diameter being 16mm, is a 14mm ball ok? Btw I will cut the tube in 2 to reduce friction.

Comment: I think it wil be fine but just make sure that the ball rolls smoothly(or if it doesn't then you can probably use 13mm or even 12mm)